# Windows 7 slipstreamed ISO

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, windows

Can I be clear and mention I'm not after pirating Windows 7. I have an MSDN subscription and I'm about to reinstall Windows 7. Is there a way of easily slipstreaming all the updates or even downloading all the updates easily enough to be able to slipstream with vLite or something?

I used to use RyanVM for XP but I haven't found something similar for Windows 7. Again, I'm not after p2p enterprise editions - I also don't trust them and neither should you!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hack7mc.com/2010/03/creating-a-windows-7-lite-for-media-center-users-with-vlite.html

Answer (score 0):

i would check out the `dism` command, which you can use the mount the Win7 WIM file to add/remove features, updates, patches, etc. [Link](http://4sysops.com/archives/windows-7-dism-how-to-mount-manage-and-service-wim-images/)